# Kafka Java API Rest proxy

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I'm new to Kafka and came up with a problem. Our Kafka cluster is accessible only through the [Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html) REST proxy and is not available to be accessed directly. There are numerous [APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#api) to access Kafka from Java, but is there a Java Wrapper around Kafka REST Proxy API?

By Java Wrappers I mean Java libraries using REST Proxy API, not Kafka native protocol.

Comment: You can use any HTTP client, not sure there needs to be a specific one to Java.

Comment: @OneCricketeer For sure. Implementing is manually is ok, but I was curious if there was something already done... Googling didn't give any results so this is why I asked the question.

Comment: [Source code is here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) - I don't see a "client" module there, as compared to the Schema Registry, for example.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks.